# How to install Lavalamp jQuery effect in wordpress

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wp_enqueue_script isn't connecting my custom js file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42985/wp-enqueue-script-isnt-connecting-my-custom-js-file)

I am having a heck of a time getting this Lavalamp effect to work on my main menu/navigation.

Here is what I have placed in the head tags:

```
<script language=""javascript"" type=""text/javascript"src="wp-content/themes/metric /scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wp-content/themes/metric/lavalamp.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type=""text/javascript"" src="wp-content/themes/metric/scripts/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type=""text/javascript"" src="wp-content/themes/metric/scripts/jquery.lavalamp.min.js"></script>

<!-- this script initiates the function change the #nav to your unordered list's ID -->
<script type=""text/javascript"">
$(function() {
$("#nav").lavaLamp({
fx: "backout",
speed: 700,
click: function(event, menuItem) {
return true;
}
});
});
</script>
```

I have made sure that my ID is the same as listed above in the code #nav.  However, it isn't working and i've hit a brick wall after trying a few different combinations.

Any help you guys could give would be much appreciated!! :)

Comment: You should enqueue your scripts and also check for errors or debug the js in firebug or chrome inspect.

Comment: Closed-voted as *exact duplicate*. Picked the question linked above, but really, [there are several from which to choose](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=wp_enqueue_script).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/metric /scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wp-content/themes/metric/lavalamp.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/metric/scripts/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/metric/scripts/jquery.lavalamp.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#nav').lavaLamp({
    fx: 'backout',
    speed: 700,
    click: function(event, menuItem) {
    return true;
    }
    });
    });
    </script>
```