# wp_enqueue_script isn't connecting my custom js file

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I am using wp_enqeue_script to link to a custom.js file in my plugins folder. However I am expecting a  link to show up on the page but it doesn't is there something else I am supposed to other than place this in the header.

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('myscript', '/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myscript.js'); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## When and where to load styles & scripts <sup>1) & 2)</sup>

> » If you are enqueueing scripts and styles, you will want to use one of these three hooks: «
>
> - `wp_enqueue_scripts` (for the frontend)
> - `login_enqueue_scripts` (for the login screen)
> - `admin_enqueue_scripts` (for the admin dashboard)
>
> » Don’t let the names fool you — they are for both scripts and styles. We’ll probably add equivalent `*_enqueue_styles` hooks in 3.4 just to make it more obvious, but these hooks have all existed for some time now.
>   A possible incompatibility with WordPress 3.3 could arise if you are using the `wp_print_styles` hook to enqueue styles — your styles may end up in the admin.
>   The fix: Use `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead. Yes, it’s that easy.
>   Edit: Yes, the same goes for registering styles. Registering or enqueueing (styles or scripts) should occur on `*_enqueue_scripts.` «

## Pathes should stay relative <sup>3)</sup>

> Keep in mind that there're
>
> - Plugins
> - MU-Plugins
> - Drop-Ins
> - Themes
> - Themes in directories registered via `register_theme_directory( $dir );`

### Debugging

1<sup>st</sup> check if the `<script>` is present in your pages source code.

✓ → The file was hooked

× → The hook is wrong (mostly too late)

2<sup>nd</sup> check if a file is missing with your Chrome Dev Bar or FF Firebug.

✓ → The file was found

× → The path or filename is wrong (mostly typo or wrong path function)

[image]

3<sup>rd</sup> try to call the file from it's path manually to determine if you have no typo.

✓ → The file was found

× → The path or filename is wrong (mostly typo or wrong path function)

#### Notes about sources:

<sup>1. [*Above is a quote Quote from WP Devel about where to add calls to `wp_enqueue/register_script/style()`:*](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/)</sup>

<sup>2. [Look at the related codex page to read the same about the hooks to use](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Usage)</sup>

<sup>3. [Another answer here on WPSE about pathes, that sums up whatcan be read in codex](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41839/using-require-once-within-admin/41892#41892)</sup>

Comment: so if I am doing it correctly, I still don't understand why I can't see the script in the outputted source.

Comment: Look into your dev bar or firebug and check the resources if the file is missing. See Update (img).

Comment: the file is missing in the resource tab. I don't understand why though. And i still don't understand why this doesn't output at a <script tag> to the html how else is the browser getting the js

Comment: Re-read the advice: Try to add the path manually and see if the file loads. If it doesn't, then you have a typo with the filename.

Comment: And if you can load it, then you need to update your Q with what exactly you tried **plus** your whole surroundings: How do you load the script, on which hook, etc. Just try to imagine, what info could would be needed to help you. Two sidenotes: Your path is simply wrong. Read the linked answer on how to set the correct path. Second: What's "connected"? Your Q-title sounds missleading.

Comment: About the `<script>` tag: It does add this tag if the script loads.

Comment: @AndersKitson So what exactly was the problem and what the solution?