# wp_enqueue has a resource but doesn't generate a script tag

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wp_enqueue_script isn't connecting my custom js file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42985/wp-enqueue-script-isnt-connecting-my-custom-js-file)

I am really confused as to how wp_enqueue_script works. I have the following code in my header, and when I inspect it in safari in the resources tab I can see it, however in the source code for the html there is nothing linking to it. So I don't understand how it shows up in the resources tab without a file linking to it. Also how would I link multiple js files using this method. I have been stuck at this all day.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'add_my_script');

function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-script',
        plugins_url('my-script.js', __FILE__),
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0',
        true
    );
}
```

Comment: When you say you have the code in your header do you mean header.php?  If so template_redirect has already fired.  You should be hooking into `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of `template_redirect`.

Comment: Or put your code in `functions.php`

Comment: to be honest I don't exactly understand this to much. If I place this is my functions.php file that js file be rendered on the page?

Comment: Actually...if you are in the theme, you shouldn't use `plugins_url`. That will lead to the wrong URL. What is the path to "my-script.js"? Are you doing this as part of a theme or a plugin?

Comment: I am doing this as part of a theme. I still don't understand how my-script.js gets linked to without a <script> tag being generated.

Comment: HONESTLY: I really tried to help you in the other Q **yesterday**. You mark the answer as solution to your problem and then open the exact same Q again? Why don't you just comment and try to update your Q until the problem is solved?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, ***but you will not see this `<script>` tag in your header!***

The last parameter of `wp_enqueue_script()` is a flag regarding whether or not to load the script at the bottom of the page.  You have this set to `true`, so you're telling WordPress to create a `<script>` tag at the *bottom* of your HTML source, not in the `<head>` element.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you should **not** be using the `template_redirect` hook for this.  Use `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );` instead.

Comment: Please see the comments on the OP. This question is an exact duplicate.