# Deregister multiple scripts using a function?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I'm trying to deregsiter multiple scripts using the following function.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );
function my_deregister_javascript() {
    if ( !is_page(array('order', 'shopping-cart', 'checkout') ) ) {
    wp_deregister_script( 'tcp_scripts' );
}
```

How do I use this function to deregsiter multiple scripts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42985/wp-enqueue-script-isnt-connecting-my-custom-js-file/42986#42986) for the correct hooks.

Answer (score 4):

First, you're attempting to deregister *too late*. You need to use `wp_enqueue_scripts`, rather than `wp_print_scripts`.

Second, all you need to do is add a call to `wp_deregister_script()` for each script you need to deregister:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );
function my_deregister_javascript() {
    if ( !is_page(array('order', 'shopping-cart', 'checkout') ) ) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'tcp_scripts' );
        // If you need to deregister more scripts when
        // this same conditional is true, just add them here
        wp_deregister_script( 'some-script' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'some-other-script' );
    }
    // If you need to deregister other scripts generally,
    // just do so here, outside the conditional:
    wp_deregister_script( 'some-third-script' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'some-fourth-script' );
}
?>
```